# within polygon: why SpatialIndex slow down query

Tags: sql, spatialite, sqlite

I create such simple demo table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl1(id INTERNAL PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE, name TEXT NOT NULL);
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('tbl1', 'geom', 4326, 'POINT', 'XY');
SELECT CreateSpatialIndex('tbl1', 'geom');
```

after that I create `180 * 360 * 60` points,
and do query:

```
spatialite> select count(*) from tbl1 where ST_Within(tbl1.geom, 
PolyFromText('POLYGON((-179 53, 179 53, 179 50, -179 50, -179 53))', 4326)) == 1;
32399
CPU Time: user 1.552150 sys 0.063322
```

Too slow, then I want to use index:

```
spatialite> select count(*) from tbl1 where ST_Within(tbl1.geom,
PolyFromText('POLYGON((-179 53, 179 53, 179 50, -179 50, -179 53))', 4326)) == 1 AND 
tbl1.ROWID IN (select ROWID from SpatialIndex where f_table_name = 'tbl1' AND f_geometry_column='geom' AND search_frame = tbl1.geom);
32399
CPU Time: user 3.325508 sys 0.066661
```

so instead of speedup, I have ~2x slow down, why?

**Update**

for the first one query `explain query plan` tells `0|0|0|SCAN TABLE tbl1`

for the second one query:

```
0|0|0|SCAN TABLE tbl1
0|0|0|EXECUTE CORRELATED LIST SUBQUERY 1
1|0|0|SCAN TABLE SpatialIndex VIRTUAL TABLE INDEX 1:
```

Comment: what does explain say?

Comment: @IanTurton I add `explain query plan` output to question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think about what your sub-query is really doing:

```
WHERE tbl1.ROWID IN 
(select ROWID from SpatialIndex where f_table_name= 'tbl1' 
AND f_geometry_column='geom' 
AND search_frame = tbl1.geom);
```

The query is searching for the rowids of points in "tbl1" by using the bounding box of the same geometries as search_frame. Every point will for sure find itself from the index but with a heavy cost and with no benefit.

You should search for the rowids of the points which are inside your **polygon** instead.

```
WHERE tbl1.ROWID IN 
(select ROWID from SpatialIndex where f_table_name = 'tbl1' 
AND f_geometry_column='geom' 
AND search_frame = 
ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((-179 53, 179 53, 179 50, -179 50, -179 53))'))
```

Comment: Thank you, but why not `search_frame = PolyFromText('POLYGON((-179 53, 179 53, 179 50, -179 50, -179 53))', 4326))` instead?

Comment: You are right, I will edit my answer. I took example from https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94072/can-spatialite-indexes-be-used-from-views but search_frame can really take the geometry directly. SRID is not needed because it is not stored into the R-Tree index and search_frame must always be in the native coordinate system.